# prove related to Cevas theorem in a given triangle

Tags: geometry

How do I prove perpendiculars from vertex opposite to sides are concurrent using only Ceva's Theorem.Or Cevians perpendicular to the opposite sides are concurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and let $D, E, F,$ be the feet of the perpendiculars opposite $A, B, C,$ respectively.

Points $B, C, E, F$ are concyclic since they all lie on the circle with diameter $BC$. Therefore, with signed lengths, we have
$$AF \cdot AB = AE \cdot AC.$$
Similarly, we have
$$BD \cdot BC = BF \cdot BA,$$
$$CE \cdot CA = CD \cdot CB.$$
Multiplying these equalities, we get
$$AF \cdot BD \cdot CE = AE \cdot BF \cdot CD.$$
$$\frac{AF}{BF}\cdot \frac{BD}{CD}\cdot\frac{CF}{AF} = 1$$
Therefore, by Ceva's theorem, the lines $AD, BE, CF$ meet at a point.